How to prove that sum of infinite complex harmonics makes a continuous time impulse function?
I was trying to substitute complex fourier series coefficients into complex fourier series formula and I came up with this identity in order to get the same function back.
How can I prove that this identity holds for each real number $t$:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{iwnt} = \frac{2\pi}{w}\delta(t),\space \space i^2 = -1$$
By knowing that$\space\delta(t)$ is the continious time unit impulse function which has area of $1$ and it's $0$ for each $t\not=0$.
By the way, if it's already proven what is the name of that proof?
Thank you so much for your help, I sweated a lot :)

You have to work in a certain space called  the distribution space.

I am slightly puzzled to see the “continuous” term. Even from what you are describing, it can’t be continuous.
What you might actually make use of is the distribution space (or rather, Schwartz space) and its dual. There, the Fourier transform is well defined and the behaviour of test functions is pretty clear. It is only straightforward from the definition of FT and delta to get the result you’re looking for.

Thank you, I have found a playlist due to your answer: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBh2i93oe2qsbptdcvFlowCl51EX_a3nB If I will be able to solve it i'll post it.

I meant that continuous time unit impulse function is a piecewise function which is defined for all real numbers, and discrete time unit impulse function is only defined for integers. you are right there is a confusion, I meant by "continuous" not the same thing that mathematicians defined, in engineering "continuous" means the domain of the function is a continuous subset of real numbers.  like [a,b] when a and b are both real. So some kind of meaning shift :)

Note first that the equality is an equality not bewteen two usual functions but between distributions.
To prove your inequality we work with test functions $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ (infinitely differentiable and finite support).
Noting the distribution $T(\omega)$ your left term, and keeping $\delta$ for the Dirac. So we have to prove :
$$ \forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}),\ \int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(t)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\omega nt }dt=\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega}\int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(t)\delta(t) dt = \dfrac{2\pi}{\omega}\varphi(0) $$
